# Cannot run docker without connection

Tags: networking, docker

Whenever I try to run docker without internet connection, I got strange messages like this

```
docker ps
2015/05/22 23:31:45 Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.12/containers/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory
```

After I connect to the network, everything works.

I have no idea how are those two things connected/related.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the version of docker, but it is most probably because of the upstart init script located at `/etc/init/docker.conf` of your Ubuntu system. 
In the version of docker that I tested (1.11.2), I observed that the core does not start until it has a network interface UP different than the loopback. If you open the aforementioned file, you may see the following:

```
description "Docker daemon"

start on (filesystem and net-device-up IFACE!=lo)
stop on runlevel [!2345]

...
```

Changing the line `start on` to allow start even without a network up is quite easy:

```
start on (filesystem and net-device-up IFACE=lo)
```

Next reboot will launch successfully the daemon.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using `boot2docker`? As per this answer on SO, https://stackoverflow.com/a/27558619/55469, in that scenario the docker daemon is essentially running on a different machine, so networking is going to be required in order to communicate with it.

Comment: No, I am not. I have Ubuntu.

Comment: Ok, so have you tried any of the solutions suggested on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294286/fata0000-get-http-var-run-docker-sock-v1-17-version-dial-unix-var-run-doc?

Comment: Starting the service actually helped. OK that was stupid. I am still not sure though why the service doesn't start without network and starts only with network...?